# limits calculation help

Tags: limits

can you help me guys to calc this two limits :
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x} $$
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan(3x)}{\tan(x)} $$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Notice that since $\ln(x)$ grows asymptotically slower than the
  polynomial $x$ as $x$  approaches $\infty$ so:
  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}=0$$
- With l'Hôpital's rule:
  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\ln(x)\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$$
- Without l'Hôpital's rule:
  $$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan(3x)}{\tan(x)}=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1+2\cos(2x)}{2\cos(2x)-1}=\frac{1+2\cos\left(2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{2\cos\left(2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-1}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use L'hospital's rule to both of them

Comment: IF the OP has encountered L'hospital's rule, THEN this is a fine hint, though If it were me posting what you wrote, I'd have posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\frac{\log x}x\le\frac{x^{1/2}}x\;\;,\;\;\;\frac{\tan 3x}{\tan x}=\frac{\sin3x}{\sin x}\cdot\frac{\cos x}{\cos3x }\;(\text{and once l'Hospital could help a lot here)}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, define $x=y+\frac \pi 2$ and use trigonometic identities $$\frac{\tan (3x)}{\tan (x)}=\frac{\tan (3(y+\frac \pi 2))}{\tan (y+\frac \pi 2)}=\frac{-\cot(3y)}{-\cot(y)}=\frac{\tan(y)}{\tan(3y)}=\frac13\frac{\tan(y)} y \frac{3y}{\tan(3y)}$$ and remember that close to $y=0$, $\tan(y)\sim y$.